# Enviar formulario para dois locais e redirecionar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, script

Preciso que o script envie meu formulario para dois locais e apos o envio seja direcionado para pagina de resposta.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function EnviaForm2()
 {
  document.getElementById('formnewsletter').action = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-wUHrhJZxfdWB7Ia_-8FxPU7o4KiL0pqVtnV0Miay_h9XxQ/formResponse';
  document.getElementById('formnewsletter').submit();
 }
 function enviaForm(nome,email){
  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "enviar.php",
      data: "&nome="+nome+"&email="+email,
      beforeSend: function() {
      },
      success: function(txt) {
     if(txt.status=='success')
      window.location.href = "https://www.paginaresposta.com";
      else
      alert("E-mail não cadastrado.");
      EnviaForm2();
      },
      error: function(txt) {
      }
    }
   );
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor? queres que o PHP execute um script? Explica a funcionalidade que pretendes e o que deve acontecer.

Comment: reformulei a pergunta